# How to generate 'format: "32FC1; compressedDepth png"' Image in python from float array?

Tags: ros, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think there's an answer that involves converting C++ code (https://github.com/ros-perception/image_transport_plugins/blob/noetic-devel/compressed_depth_image_transport/src/codec.cpp) to python- does anyone have a block of code where this is already done?  Or do the right arguments to `CvBridge.cv2_to_compressed_imgmsg` work for this?

This goes the other direction https://answers.ros.org/question/249775/display-compresseddepth-image-python-cv2/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407659/how-to-generate-%27format:-%2232fc1;-compresseddepth-png%22%27-image-in-python-from-float-array?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2022-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is what I came up with- I haven't yet checked to make sure the depth values when decompressed are correct, they just seemed reasonable as seen in rqt:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sensor_msgs.msg import CompressedImage


def encode_compressed_depth_image_msg(depth_image: np.array,
                                      depth_min=1.0, depth_max=10.0,
                                      depth_quantization=100.0):
    depth_image[depth_image > depth_max] = np.nan
    depth_image[depth_image < depth_min] = np.nan
    depth_z0 = depth_quantization
    depth_quant_a = depth_z0 * (depth_z0 + 1.0)
    depth_quant_b = 1.0 - depth_quant_a / depth_max
    inv_depth = (depth_quant_a / depth_image + depth_quant_b).astype(np.uint16)
    depth_encoded = cv2.imencode(".png", inv_depth)[1]
    header = np.array([0.0, depth_quant_a, depth_quant_b], np.float32)

    compressed_depth_msg = CompressedImage()
    compressed_depth_msg.format = "32FC1; compressedDepth png"
    compressed_depth_msg.data = header.tobytes() + depth_encoded.tobytes()
    return compressed_depth_msg
```

The payload of the CompressedDepth `"32FC1; compressedDepth png"` is 12 header bytes which contains the conversion scaling numbers quant a & b, then an encoded 16-bit grayscale png follows (if you lop off those first 12 bytes and save the rest of the bytes to a file you can display it in a png viewer and see the depth values).  The scaling numbers fixed above but could be changed *per-frame* if there was a reason to, by manipulating depth_max and depth_quantization (or refactor so depth_quant_a and b are set through some other means).

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2022-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0